# Website html form with image attachment ...cant get the attachment via email

Tags: php, html, base64, image-upload

I am trying to make a form that user can upload their own image through the website contact form...however, i can receive the input wordings but not the attachment...does anyone can point out the error?

> ```
> //Settings 
> $max_allowed_file_size = 10000; // size in KB
> $allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp");
> $upload_folder = './uploads/'; //<-- this folder must be writeable by the script
> $your_email = 'tcc@hotmail.com';//<<--  update this to your email address
>
> $errors ='';
>
> if(isset($_POST['submit']))
> {
>   //Get the uploaded file information
>   $name_of_uploaded_file =  basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
>
>   //get the file extension of the file
>   $type_of_uploaded_file = substr($name_of_uploaded_file, 
>                           strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);
>
>   $size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]/1024;
>
>   ///------------Do Validations-------------
>   if(empty($_POST['name'])||empty($_POST['email']))
>   {
>       $errors .= "\n Name and Email are required fields. ";   
>   }
>   if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
>   {
>       $errors .= "\n Bad email value!";
>   }
>
>   if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size ) 
>   {
>       $errors .= "\n Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size";
>   }
>
>   //------ Validate the file extension -----
>   $allowed_ext = false;
>   for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++) 
>   { 
>       if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
>       {
>           $allowed_ext = true;        
>       }
>   }
>
>   if(!$allowed_ext)
>   {
>       $errors .= "\n The uploaded file is not supported file type. ".
>       " Only the following file types are supported: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
>   }
>
>   //send the email 
>   if(empty($errors))
>   {
>       //copy the temp. uploaded file to uploads folder
>       $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder . $name_of_uploaded_file;
>       $tmp_path = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];
>
>       if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path))
>       {
>           if(!copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file))
>           {
>               $errors .= '\n error while copying the uploaded file';
>           }
>       }
>
>   }}
>   ?>
>
>
>
>
>       //send the email
>        <?php
> if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
> //define the receiver of the email
> $to = 'tcc@hotmail.com';
> //define the subject of the email
> $subject = 'Decor';
> //create a boundary string. It must be unique
> //so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
> $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
> //define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
> $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
> //add boundary string and mime type specification
> $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
> //read the atachment file contents into a string,
> //encode it with MIME base64,
> //and split it into smaller chunks
> $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('./uploads/'.$_POST[$path_of_uploaded_file])));
> //define the body of the message.
> ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
> ?>
> --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"
>
> --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Name: <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>
> Email: <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>
> Picture Name: <?php echo $_POST['picname']; ?>
> Description: <?php echo $_POST['description']; ?>
>
> --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
> Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>
> Name: <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?><br/>
> Email: <?php echo $_POST['email']; ?><br/>
> Picture Name: <?php echo $_POST['picname']; ?><br/>
> Description: <?php echo $_POST['description']; ?><br/>
>
> --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
>
> --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
> Content-Type: data:image/jpg; name="photo.jpg " 
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
> Content-Disposition: attachment 
>
> <?php echo $attachment; ?>
> --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
>
> <?php
> //copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
> $message = ob_get_clean();
> //send the email
> $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;
>
>     if ($sent) {
>       header("Location: http://www.tcc.hk/vday2014/thanks.php");
>       exit();
>     } else {
>       print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; 
>     }
>
>
>
>
> }
> ?>
>
> <?
> ///////////////////////////Functions/////////////////
> // Function to validate against any email injection attempts
> function IsInjected($str)
> {
>   $injections = array('(\n+)',
>               '(\r+)',
>               '(\t+)',
>               '(%0A+)',
>               '(%0D+)',
>               '(%08+)',
>               '(%09+)'
>               );
>   $inject = join('|', $injections);
>   $inject = "/$inject/i";
>   if(preg_match($inject,$str))
>     {
>     return true;
>   }
>   else
>     {
>     return false;
>   }
> }
> ?>
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
> <html>
> <head>
>   <title>File upload form</title>
> <!-- define some style elements-->
> <style>
> label,a, body 
> {
>   font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
>   font-size : 12px; 
> }
>
> </style>  
> <!-- a helper script for vaidating the form-->
> <script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
> </head>
>
> <body>
> <?php
> if(!empty($errors))
> {
>   echo nl2br($errors);
> }
> ?>
> <form method="POST" name="email_form_with_php" 
>
> onsubmit="return validateForm()"
>
> > 
> <p>
> <label for='name'>Name: </label><br>
> <input type="text" name="name" >
> </p>
> <p>
> <label for='email'>Email: </label><br>
> <input type="text" name="email" >
> </p>
> <p>
> <label for='message'>Message:</label> <br>
> <textarea name="message"></textarea>
> </p>
> <p>
> <label for='uploaded_file'>Select A File To Upload:</label> <br>
> <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
> </p>
> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit'>
> </form>
> <script language="JavaScript">
> // Code for validating the form
> // Visit http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml
> // for details
> var frmvalidator  = new Validator("email_form_with_php");
> frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
> frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
> frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
> </script>
> <noscript>
> <small><a href='http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html'
> >How to attach file to email in PHP</a> article page.</small>
> </noscript>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Form (same doc)

> ```
> <form method="POST" name="email_form_with_php" 
>
> onsubmit="return validateForm()"
>
> > 
> <p>
> <label for='name'>Name: </label><br>
> <input type="text" name="name" >
> </p>
> <p>
> <label for='email'>Email: </label><br>
> <input type="text" name="email" >
> </p>
> <p>
> <label for='message'>Message:</label> <br>
> <textarea name="message"></textarea>
> </p>
> <p>
> <label for='uploaded_file'>Select A File To Upload:</label> <br>
> <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
> </p>
> <input type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit'>
> </form>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Set the enctype attribute in your form to "multipart/form-data"   Otherwise, file fields don't work.

Comment: ummm...still cannot get the attachment....i am wondering is it because of this..

$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://www.tcc.com/vday2014/test/uploads/'.$_POST[$path_of_uploaded_file])));

Comment: May I ask why you aren't using something like PHPMailer or SwiftMailer which handles all of that header writing for you?  It would make the job much easier to code, and better yet, easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

In your form you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

So i.e:

```
<form method="POST" name="email_form_with_php" 
enctype="multipart/form-data"
onsubmit="return validateForm()"
>
```

Comment: ummm...still cannot get the attachment....i am wondering is it because of this..

$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://www.tcc.com/vday2014/test/uploads/'.$_POST[$path_of_uploaded_file])));